# Problems with Playn libraries installation and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu, playn

I need the Playn libraries for an important project and I can't make them work on Linux. All the first part run smooth, I've installed git, and launched the clone command from terminal, I've installed maven and the mvn test went fine, then I've installed the maven add-on for Eclipse an rebooted. Then I've created a blank project in the workspace folder with the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.playn                   -DarchetypeArtifactId=playn-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.7
```

Now I only have to import it and this is where the problem start, every time I tried I get the same errors.

[image: errors]

Now I think that I can resolve all but the last two by adding some plug-in and packages, but how can I fix the last two? This has been haunting me for days and I've even found out that is a common problem but I don't understand a word about its solution. There must be a package or something that fix that, if not I need a step by step guide on how to fix it cause I've only used Eclipse for debugging, and I've never ever messed with Playn before.
I'm running on Ubuntu 32 bit, it's the last release.

Comment: Any reason for not using the 'mavenize' option in eclipse, right click on project, configure, convert to maven project? Then clone the needed libraries in your project directory and refresh the view (F5). Or use 'egit' for using git from eclipse.

Comment: I have no idea what are you talking about, as I've said I'm a novice. The project I have to import is already a maven project, also I have to import it so there is still no project to click on it, I assume you are suggesting to create a normal project and then turn it into a maven project? The procedure I've followed is the one suggested in the assignment, if there is a more friendly way to start a project and not encounter errors I would love to ear it with a little bit more of details.